# Python range() implementation in django templates

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have some django application, i need to render some html with this block of code:

```
{% for i in review.mark|range %}
     img src="{% static 'core/img/star-yellow.svg' %}" alt="star">
{% endfor %}
```

Sometimes filter range help me with this (review.mark is only IntegerField in my model). I have mark from 1 to 5, and i want to loop for `review.mark` times. How can i do this in django templates?

Answer (score 0):

we can do like below

```
{% load static %}
{% for _ in "x"|rjust:review.mark %}
  <img src="{% static 'core/img/star-yellow.svg' %}" alt="star" />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: rjust add review.mark spaces before "x", so i think i should add review.mark - 1 spaces to get correct iteration?

Comment: @Vladyslav yeah, is it worked for you ?